# Is it haram if a person masturbated but didn’t know?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it haram to masturbate once?

Is it haram if you masturbated before but didn’t know it was forbidden?

Comment: If something is **haram** then it can't be **halal** by any means. The point is rather whether it is regarded as a sin doing it without knowing the ruling.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. If you didn’t know something was haram, it won’t be filed against you. Next time, stay informed.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no mention of masturbation in the Quran but scholars differ over whether its haram or not.

I suppose the scholars who say it is haram quote this as their proof

- *And those who guard their chastity (i.e. private parts from* *illegal sexual acts) .*

**Except with their wives and the (women slaves and* *captives) whom their right hands possess, for (then) they are* *not to be blamed [ Al-Ma’arij 29&30]*

But then again, I don’t think this makes it clear that masturbation is haram and it could refer to actual sex

Comment: How come It shouldn't? Masturbation is a sexual activity that involves sexual pleasure. Also, the debate is on whether It is makrooh or completely haram and a sin to do so, none of the scholars say that It is completely halal.